# Listen for mouseover and mouseout <li> events only? Elements inside <li> currently triggers both events

Tags: javascript

How can I listen for mouseover and mouseout events on a `<li>` without triggering both events when hovering elements inside of the `<li>`?

I currently have a listing structure with several `<li>`'s. Inside each `<li>` there are several `<div>`'s which are either `position: relative;` or `position: absolute;`

The listeners looks as followed:

```
blockContainer.children[i].addEventListener("mouseover", function(e) {
...
});

blockContainer.children[i].addEventListener("mouseout", function(e) {
...
});
```

I've added a fiddle test here: http://jsfiddle.net/L334eymv/

Note how the blue div triggers again and again when you hover it aswell as the green div.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/L334eymv/3/

Comment: ahh yess, so its as simple as using mouseenter and mouseleave?? oh darn :)

Comment: Yup. Same as mouseover/mouseout but event doesn't bubble.

Comment: you should leave an answer, so I can choose it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to affect only target elements, you should use [mouseenter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseenter) and [mouseleave](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseleave) events. They behave like mouseover/mouseout except they don't bubble.